# link_to first name and last name as one link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, link-to

I have the first name and last name which both link to the users profile:

```
= link_to (@post.user.fname), user_path(@post.user_id) 
= link_to (@post.user.lname), user_path(@post.user_id)
```

These are two separate links. When I hover the mouse over the first name it only highlights the first name. And vice versa. (Example is just a randomly generated name)

How do I make the first name and last name one single link_to so it underlines the full name?

[image]

Comment: please mark the answer correct: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43662353/1536309

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Join names with [`string interpolation`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation):

```
= link_to "#{@post.user.fname} #{@post.user.lname}", user_path(@post.user_id)
```

There is a more good solution, add a method to the user model which returns the full name.

```
#app/models/user.rb

def full_name
  "#{fname} #{lname}"
end
```

And use it in the `link_to` helper:

```
 = link_to @post.user.full_name, user_path(@post.user_id)
```

There is another solution, use the [`delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) method, here is an example:

```
#app/models/post.rb

# Obviously post belongs to user
belongs_to :user
delegate :full_name, to: :user
# which means if the `full_name` method 
# invokes on the @post model `delegate` it to user
```

Usage:

```
= link_to @post.full_name, user_path(@post.user_id)
```

Here is another example of *Rails magic*:

```
= link_to @post.full_name, @post.user
```

As you can see I omit the `user_path` helper and just pass an `@post.user` object, Rails able to construct path helper for me under the hood.

Comment: plus one for the delegate

Comment: Simple and great explanation!

Comment: I have a couple new things to read up on, Thanks for the simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

If first or last can be blank, you can do this sort of thing:

```
#app/models/user.rb

def full_name
  [fname.presence, lname.presence].compact.join(' ')
end
```